# Ruby decompose UTF-8 chars

Tags: ruby, string, encoding, utf-8, utf-16

I achieved to get the UTF-16 code of "ü" using

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: UTF-8

puts "ü".unpack('U*')
```

Well, it just returns `252` which is fine.
I read the online doc for ruby String but I don't get it how to decompose this character.

In case of `ü` I want to get the character `u (117)` and `¨ (168)`

Thanks in advance,
I appreciate any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String#unpack` and `Array#pack` are, as ForeverZer0 mentioned in the comments, for decoding binary strings into more structured data (such as numbers) and encoding data into strings (respectively). If you want to decompose unicode, you want [`String#unicode_normalize`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-unicode_normalize) and the NFD form:

```
> "ü".unicode_normalize(:nfd).chars
 => ["u", "̈"]
```

That gives you 117 and 776, not 168. 168 is `¨` in ISO-8859-1 not UTF-8.

Comment: There's a built in now, awesome! Note it's 776 because they are two different Unicode code points. ü, U+00FC, [decomposes into U+0075 and U+0308](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fc/index.htm). 776 is 308 in hex or [U+0308 COMBINING DIARESIS](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0308/index.htm). 168 is a8 in hex or [U+00A8 DIARESIS](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a8/index.htm). Verify with `"ü".unicode_normalize(:nfd).each_codepoint { |i| puts i.to_s(16) }`

Comment: @Schwern Thanks for the clarification on 0xA8. I assumed that they were looking at a Latin-1 chart for the diaresis.

Comment: I see why. The Latin-1 encoding for a diaeresis is the same as the Unicode code point: x0A8 or 168.

Comment: @Schwern On the upside, encodings are less of a nightmare than they were 20 years ago. I remember dealing with Latin-n, Windows CPn, JIS, SJIS, EUC, and all that nonsense.

Comment: I have a copy of O'Reilly's *CJKV Information Processing*. It's 1100 pages. Half of that of that is nothing but code tables back when you couldn't just look this stuff up on the Internet. When people complain about Unicode I want to throw that book at them.

Comment: @Schwern I used the tables in that book to check some encoding stuff back in the day, difficult when you can't read kanji and have to eyeball the glyphs. Kids these days, they can just go ahead and get off my lawn ;)